# SilverLight Reference Error

Tags: wpf, silverlight

I declared `mlns:icons="clr-namespace:Pro.Icons"` at the top of the xaml file and then I tried o use it `<icons:VLogo Cursor="Hand"...`. and it shows me a designer error

> Error 14 The type 'icons:VLogo' was not found. Verify that you are not
>   missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have
>   been built.

I am quite new to SilverLight so maybe my question is not so clear. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

See the section "Mapping Prefixes to CLR Namespaces and Assemblies" in this article [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189061(v=vs.95).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189061%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) where it describes including the assembly name in your xmlns declaration.  Also make sure you have a reference to the Pro.Icons.dll in your project